# How to add animation in view onto another view in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

i am new in iphone. I developing an application and i want to add a view into another view but it will  show down to up with animation, some one help me to do that.

Comment: what want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope it'll work...

```
[self.view addSubview:yourView];
[yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 460)];
[yourView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 460)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view addSubview:yourView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, use `presentModalViewController`. Here's an example:

```
SecondViewController *aSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
aSecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];
```

Just don't forget to add the header to your SecondViewController to the first view controller's .h file